# HP ProBook 6570b maximum resolution - is 3840 x 2160 / 4K possible?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, display

I'd like to hook up a HP ProBook 6570b to a 4K display. Before getting one, I'd like to know if the laptop is capable of outputting 3840 x 2160 @ 30Hz via the DisplayPort.

My current research indicates that ProBook 6570b is not capable of anything above 2560x1600:

[HP ProBook 6570b specs, page 7](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14308_na/14308_na.pdf): Maximum is 2560x1600@60Hz

[Intel HD Graphics 4000](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics) (ProBook 6570b graphics card): Maximum 2560x1600

Since I'm willing to go 30Hz, I'm hoping that despite the evidence, there's a chance of going above 2560x1600. Any workaround suggestions (DisplayLink 4k?) are also appreciated.

Comment: It seems to have switchable graphics. If I understood it correctly then **all** graphics is output by the Intel chip and the AMD is just used for calculations. Similar post with intel/Nvidia/optimus questions can be found on this site and indeed limit the resolution while running windows.  (Interestingly enough Linux was capable of higher resolutions, so that is a driver issue).  Mind you that performace at 4K might be slow. Good enough for office work. Very much not for gaming.

Answer (score 1):

Not Happening. You usually need a pretty beefy video card to crank out a resolution that high. Integrated GPUs on most laptops are notoriously weak.